# Foundation 6.1.2 for sites not compiling javascripts from gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation-6

Having issues with Foundation 6.1.2 for sites not compiling javascripts from gulpfile.js - sometimes it will work more often than not it wont. and I will end up with an "uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined" error.

this is a stock "foundation new --framework sites --template zurb --directory " installation. with no changes to the gulpfile.js. My app.js contains just $(document).foundation(); that is it!

Like I say sometimes, the individual javascript files will get compiled into /dist/assets/js/app.js more often they won't.

there are no console errors and nothing output to the terminal other than the ordinary success output [no errors in teminal either - I've tried both the cygwin & sublime terminals -both the same.]

Has anyone see this and have a fix... it's incredibly frustrating!!

Comment: What version of Node/NPM are you using?

Comment: not sure. i updated node less than a week ago.

Comment: some bug in the version of the template that zurb provided. downloaded an updated template from github and it works fine now.

Comment: "some bug in the version of the template that zurb provided. downloaded an updated template from github and it works fine now."

So this is solved?
Then please answer your question yourself and mark it as solution.